# Exported receiver does not require permission for 2 receiver

Tags: android

Exported receiver does not require permission

i got these warning, and my code for notification buttons can't work mean images of button can't change for play/pause button.

I am using RemoteViews because of that i am not able to use OnClickListener. so i use 2 receiver to exchange 2 xml files to exchange them in notification (1 having play button, 2having pause button) but it can't work.

Comment: sounds like you need to use "updateNotification" but you didn't post code and you don't explain what "can't work" means... do you have errors? Post a logcat...

Comment: No @Jim actually we don't have any kind of error and we just want to change the Image of button but it can't work, we play/pause the MediaPlayer but the image is not change.
i told what we did..
We use RemoteView in our class through which we call BroadcastReceiver in class which extends BroadcastReceiver we do the matching action to intent it work fine if we do separate button for play and pause. 
Now we take 2 BroadcastReceiver 1 having play.xml view and other having pause.xml view we just want to interchange the views but 2nd BroadcastReceiver doesn't even get called..

Comment: post your code. I use remoteviews for something that sounds similar, but I'm not sure it will work for you

Comment: @Jim My code is big so put it on Git Please follow the link...
I Post here my Notification code and below that i Post my BroadcastReceiver

https://gist.github.com/18ulhaspatil/284dde0d7f3fa6b56b9d

Comment: What is your manifest? Do you have all the intent filters setup for the receiver properly?

Comment: I do @Jim, finally we did it...
The thing is, only we have to use 2 xml having our required buttons(Means 1have Pause button and other having Play) and we have to fetch other in our BroadcastReceiver...
Thanx for ur Reply